# people can't call my s3 after I have already unblocked them

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I enabled blocking mode & blocked 1 contact. After that the person can't still contact me eventhrough I have unblocked that contact already. How to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your phone?

Comment: Yes I have tried restarting my phones 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

"Blocking mode" has nothing to do with blocking individual contacts. It stops all calls and other notifications disturbing you, like a "do not disturb" mode. If you want people to call you, turn off blocking mode.